# JavaScript: a better way to extract every 5th item from an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of tuples of coordinates like

```js
[ [ 1, 1 ],
  [ 2, 2 ],
  [ 3, 3 ],
  [ 4, 4 ],
  [ 5, 5 ],
  [ 6, 6 ],
  [ 7, 7 ],
  [ 8, 8 ],
  [ 9, 9 ],
  [ 10, 10 ]
  ...
```

I want to extract every 5th coordinates out of them into a new array

Here is my implementation

```js
const coordinates = Array.from({ length: 30 }, (_, i) => [i + 1, i + 1])

const { filteredCoordinates } = coordinates.reduce(
  (accu, currCoordinate) => {
    if (accu.count === 5) {
      accu.filteredCoordinates.push(currCoordinate)
      accu.count = 1
    } else {
      accu.count += 1
    }
    return accu
  },
  {
    count: 1,
    filteredCoordinates: [],
  }
)

console.log(filteredCoordinates);
```

This works fine but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: What is the goal here? You used a `reduce` - I assume there is a reason you didn't just use `for(let i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i += 5)` but I can't see why.

Comment: By "extract" do you mean remove the coords from the first array to the second, or just make a copy of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the array based on the modulo of five given the index.

```js
const coordinates = Array.from({ length: 30 }, (_, i) => [i + 1, i + 1])

const everyFithCoordinate = coordinates.filter((_, i) => (i+1) % 5 === 0);

console.log(everyFithCoordinate);
```

Comment: I _think_ it'd be `(i + 1) % 5 === 0` based on the question, but this is probably how I'd do it. That being said, it's not necessarily more efficient than OP's method

Comment: Yea, you might be right @Nick. Especially given the code OP provided.

Answer (score 2):

You could take an index and increment it by the wanted count.

This approach does not iterate the complete array, only the wanted indices.

```js
const
    coordinates = Array.from({ length: 30 }, (_, i) => [i + 1, i + 1]),
    filtered = [];

for (let i = 4; i < coordinates.length; i += 5) filtered.push(coordinates[i]);

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to loop over completely, You can just use traditional `for` loop and increment it with `step` i.e 5

```js
const coordinates = Array.from({ length: 30 }, (_, i) => [i + 1, i + 1]);

const result = [];
const step = 5;
for (let i = step - 1; i < coordinates.length; i += step) {
  result.push(coordinates[i]);
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to extract every 5th coordinates out of them into a new array

Depending on your definition of "extract" you may be wanting to move those coordinates from the first to the second array. This example uses a [`for statement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement). I cache the length, and then [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) out the coordinate from the array at the given index, and push it into the new array. Then decrement both the length and the index because they have changed before the next iteration.

```js
const coordinates = Array.from({ length: 32 }, (_, i) => [i + 1, i + 1]);

const out = [];
const count = 5;
let { length } = coordinates;

for (let i = count - 1; i < length; i += count) {
  out.push(coordinates.splice(i, 1)[0]);
  --length;
  --i;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(out));
console.log(JSON.stringify(coordinates));
```

Answer (score -1):

The proper and efficient functional way to achieve this task is done by using `Array.from()`. However as far as i can see nobody has implemented it properly so far. Lets try.

```js
var coords = Array.from({ length: 30 }, (_, i) => [i + 1, i + 1]),
    period = 5,
    result = Array.from( {length : ~~(coords.length / period)}
                       , (_,i) => coords[i*period+period-1]
                       );
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for answering. this is really cool but why are you still using var I am just curious

Comment: I think that there is absolutely no reason to trash `var` in JS. I almost never use `const` in my code unless i write a library function expression or such. I use `let` time to time when there is a need for it, such as limiting the variable into a certain context or block. `var` is friendly.